# PostgreSQL WAL into mountain

Tags: postgresql, distributed, logging

it's more or less a simple yes or no question...

Can I configure PostgrSQL to WAL into a swiss cave somewhere in the alps and WAL localy at the same time?

If yes, can you set some soft time goal how long commits can be batched together before they are flushed into the mountain? Having tonnes of single tcp ping pong stuff might not be so efficent?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: yes.

Read about the [different replication solutions available for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/different-replication-solutions.html) before deciding on a particular backup method.

It sounds like you're looking for [PostgreSQL's Continuous Archiving/PITR backup method](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html).

And have you read the [PostgreSQL WAL Log Shipping](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html) documentation?